# GtkTreeView's row right click

Tags: click, pygtk, right-click, treeviewitem, gtktreeview

How do I do something when user right click in a treeview's row?

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer on here and accept it.

Answer (score 3):

It's really easy, just listen to the "button-press-event" signal and use `treeview.get_path_at_pos()` to figure the selected row:

```python
def button_press_event(treeview, event):
    if event.button == 3: # right click
        model, path = treeview.get_path_at_pos(int(event.x), int(event.y))
        # do something with the selected path

treeview.connect('button-press-event' , button_press_event)
```

Comment: See also: [Chapter 16: Menus](http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/menus.html) from the Python Gtk+ 3.0 tutorial.

Comment: Maybe it's GTK2 vs GTK3, but according to [pygtk 2 doc](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2reference/class-gtktreeview.html#method-gtktreeview--get-path-at-pos) it should be something like `path, column, __, __ = treeview.get_path_at_pos(int(event.x), int(event.y))`

Comment: Watch out: you don't necessarily want "button-press-event" unless your aim is to show a popup menu. If for instance you want to just execute some action on the clicked row, you will want "button-release-event". This will guarantee that when you right click on a new row, it gets selected (default handler for "button-press-event") before anything else happens.

Comment: @PietroBattiston you can return True/False to control whether that kind of event propagation should happen or not.

Comment: Yes, but order can matter: you probably want to first have the line selected, then execute your callback with the updated selection. (plus: in general - popups are an exception - whenever you say "click" you mean "button release")

Comment: @PietroBattiston Yes, popups should generally be release, but for other actions that you want to happen later, you can use gobject.idle_add(), not pretty but it works.

Comment: @JohanDahlin no, I think popups should be "press", and precisely in this sense they are an exception. Yes, you'll probably get the same result with glib.idle_add() , it's just more complicated and I fail to see any benefit.